# Anchor tag is not working properly in email. how to correct this URL?

Tags: php

Actually I am facing when I am trying to send a link in the (PHP) email. when i click on the link then the browser is adding special characters in the link.

i am trying :

```
$testid = "4215";
 $testid2 = "566";
 $link = "https://www.test.com/page/test.php?pbid='".$testid."'&about=1_'".$testid2."'";
 $email_desc .= "test <a href='".$link."'>here</a>";
```

and when i am click on this link the email then in the browser i get url like this which is not working:

```
https://www.test.com/page/test.php?pbid=\%27330\%27&test=1_\%27367\%27
```

But I need is URL like :

```
https://www.test.com/page/test.php?pbid=330&test=1_367
```

Comment: Typo.  You've included single-quotes in your URL, just remove them.

Comment: In this case not make link.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  What's the exact problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation is wrong so that link is not proper render.
Try below code:

```
$testid = "4215";
$testid2 = "566";                
$link = "https://www.test.com/page/test.php?pbid=".$testid."&about=1_".$testid2;
$email_desc .= "test <a href='".$link."'>here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply Try it like this

```
 $link = "https://www.test.com/page/test.php?pbid=".$testid."&about=1_".$testid2."";
```

Hope it helps